# Gremlin/AWS Neptune: Adding Edge w/ Properties

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I currently have a series of two vertices in a parent/child relationship, two edges between them that I have no issue with.

The issue happens when I start attempting to add properties to the edge and I get an error message that gives only some help:

```
{
    "requestId": "...",
    "code": "InternalFailureException",
    "detailedMessage": "null:to([[SelectOneStep(last,child)]])"
}
```

I can run the same pattern below on Gremlify, but I understand that is 3.5 as opposed to Neptune on 3.4.

Do I need to point back to the edge itself after adding in all the properties or am I supposed to specify `to(select('child'))` and then add all the properties while in scope (and then return back to `child`)?

Traversal Query:

```
g.V(13695)
    .out("latest_parent_to").as("child")
    .in("parent_to")
    .addE("role")
        .property(single,'name','some_role')
    .to(
        select("child")    
    ).select("child")
```

Update: I made a few changes to try the other thought: addE > to(select(...)) > set properties. Different error this time:

```
{
    "requestId": "77ee2b5b-8309-4226-b163-8b253450c721",
    "code": "UnsupportedOperationException",
    "detailedMessage": "Cardinality specification may not be used with Edge properties."
}
```

The reason for using the single cardinality is every property stored/returned as a set. This was to prevent accidentally appending when one should update.

Comment: At face value your query looks fine. Is it possible that `g.V(13695)
    .out("latest_parent_to").as("child")` is not actually yielding any results?

Comment: @Kelvin I know that this record exists in the neptune instance. That is just the ID from my Gremlify testing.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. I used essentially your query on one of my Neptune graphs and it worked fine.  The `null` in the error message leads me to believe that something in the query failed to yield a result but I cannot as yet explain it.

Comment: @Kelvin Updating my question as I did try something different and got a very different error message. Might change some thought.

Comment: Can you try removing the cardinality argument as the Edge properties are single cardinality always by default.

Comment: That did make it work, but it appears that the same property cannot be altered.

Comment: A property should always be modifiable. Can you please update the question with the exact query being run as I am not able to reproduce any of these issues? Also which Neptune engine version are you running?